# ParametricNDSolve for a system of two differentia equations

Tags: differential-equations, event-detection

Is there a  way to plot the system of the code below?
How can I get the value of `s` for [`WhenEvent`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WhenEvent.html) happens for each parameter?

```
Γ = 5/3;
c4 = 6;
smax = 50;
Rinit = 1.05;
γuinit = 0.80;
Sol3 = ParametricNDSolveValue[{D1[s] == 
2 (-1 + R[s]) R[
  s] (-(-1 + Γ) γu[s] + 
   c4 ((-1 + R[s]) R[s]^3)^((1 - Γ)/
    2) (-2 + Γ) Γ γu[s]^(
    2 - Γ) + 
   c4 ((-1 + R[s]) R[s]^3)^((1 - Γ)/
    2) (-1 + Γ) Γ γu[
     s]^-Γ), 
   N1[s] == -(1 + γu[s]^2) (1 - Γ + 
   c4 (-1 + R[s])^(1/2 - Γ/2)
   R[s]^(-(3/2) (-1 + Γ)) (2 + 
   4 R[s] (-1 + Γ) - 
   3 Γ) Γ γu[s]^(
   1 - Γ)), R'[s] == D1[s]/Sqrt[D1[s]^2 + N1[s]^2],
  Derivative[1][γu][s] == N1[s]/Sqrt[D1[s]^2 + N1[s]^2], 
R[0] == Rinit, γu[0] == d, 
WhenEvent[N1[s]* D1[s] == 0, smax = s; 
 "Stop Integration"]}, {R, γu}, {s, 0, smax}, {d}]
```

Comment: There are **[things to do after your question is answered](https://wolfr.am/v57DB3p4)**. While it's a good idea to stay vigilant for some time, better approaches may come later improving over previous replies. Experienced users may point out alternatives, caveats or limitations and users should **test answers before [voting](https://wolfr.am/v57ItzJq)** and **wait 24 hours before [accepting](https://wolfr.am/v57LwTXD)** the best one. Participation is essential for the site, please do your part. Enough time has passed, should any of these answers be accepted?

Answer (score 1):

Note, it looks like the `WhenEvent` never happens. Here you can see the functions for d=1..100.

```
Manipulate[
 Column[{
   Plot[Through[Sol3[d][s]], {s, 0, smax}],
   StringForm["smax= ``", smax]
   }],
 {d, 1, 100}]
```

[image]

The two function may be plotted separately by:

```
funs[x_] = Table[Sol3[i][[1]][x], {i, 1, 5}];
Plot[Evaluate@funs[x], {x, 0, smax}, PlotLabel -> "R"]
```

[image]

```
funs[x_] = Table[Sol3[i][[2]][x], {i, 1, 5}];
Plot[Evaluate@funs[x], {x, 0, smax}, PlotLabel -> "\[Gamma]u"]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  Is there a way to visualize all the plots for the different parameters at the same time?

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific?

Comment: Lets say if the parameter d takes 5 different values between 1 and 5 i would like to plot 5 different curves at the same axes. A line for d=1, d=2 ,d=3, d=4 d=5. And be able to see all of them so as to compare them. I hope this helps.

Comment: I made an addition to my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for all your trouble. And one final question if i may. How can i plot the ParametricPlot[R[s],γ[υ]] at the same axes for all the parameters d?

Comment: Do you mean the last 2 plots together?

Comment: You have plotted R as a function of s and γυ as a function of s. I would like the have the plot of γυ[s] as a function of R[s]. γu on the y axis and R on the x axis. I hoped this is more clear.

Answer (score 1):

To plot `γu` against `R` is a bit more complicated. We first calculate `γu` and `R` for different parameters `d` and `s`. Then we gather the values of `γu` and `R` for the same value of `d` but different values of `s` and create an interpolation function from these values. This gives us a bunch on interpolation functions `γu` against `R` for different `d`.

First we need the `γu` and `R`:

```
\[CapitalGamma] = 5/3; c4 = 6;
smax = 50;
Rinit = 1.05;
\[Gamma]uinit = 0.80;
Sol3 = ParametricNDSolveValue[{D1[s] == 
    2 (-1 + R[s]) R[
      s] (-(-1 + \[CapitalGamma]) \[Gamma]u[s] + 
       c4 ((-1 + R[s]) R[s]^3)^((1 - \[CapitalGamma])/
           2) (-2 + \[CapitalGamma]) \[CapitalGamma] \[Gamma]u[
          s]^(2 - \[CapitalGamma]) + 
       c4 ((-1 + R[s]) R[s]^3)^((1 - \[CapitalGamma])/
           2) (-1 + \[CapitalGamma]) \[CapitalGamma] \[Gamma]u[
          s]^-\[CapitalGamma]), 
   N1[s] == -(1 + \[Gamma]u[s]^2) (1 - \[CapitalGamma] + 
       c4 (-1 + R[s])^(1/2 - \[CapitalGamma]/2) R[
          s]^(-(3/2) (-1 + \[CapitalGamma])) (2 + 
          4 R[s] (-1 + \[CapitalGamma]) - 
          3 \[CapitalGamma]) \[CapitalGamma] \[Gamma]u[
          s]^(1 - \[CapitalGamma])), 
   R'[s] == D1[s]/Sqrt[D1[s]^2 + N1[s]^2], 
   Derivative[1][\[Gamma]u][s] == N1[s]/Sqrt[D1[s]^2 + N1[s]^2], 
   R[0] == Rinit, \[Gamma]u[0] == d, 
   WhenEvent[N1[s]*D1[s] == 0, smax = s;
    "Stop Integration"]}, {R, \[Gamma]u}, {s, 0, smax}, {d}]
```

Then we get functions for `γu` and `R` for different `d` :

```
funsR[x_] = Table[Sol3[i][[1]][x], {i, 1, 5}];
funsGam[x_] = Table[Sol3[i][[2]][x], {i, 1, 5}];
```

Now we get values for these functions for different `s`:

```
tab = Table[{funsR[x], funsGam[x]}, {x, 0, smax, smax/5}];
```

From these values we now create functions `γu` against `R` for different `d`

```
funs[x_] = Interpolation[#][x] & /@ Transpose[Transpose /@ tab]
```

Finally we plot these functions (note that you will get some warnings because we use extrapolation):

```
Plot[Evaluate@funs[x], {x, 1.04, 1.06}, AxesLabel -> {"R", "\[Gamma]u"}]
```

[image]